# Need explanation of how this circuit works

Tags: random

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7rYZe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've been making this *decision maker* at my electronics class which lights up either one of the leds when the switch is closed at random but I never understood how this circuit works nor did I get a clear explanation from my teacher :/   The power supply of 1V seems crazy to me , it cant be right?

can somebody please explain to me how this circuit works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that all the numbers on that shematic are potentially wrong, as that setup will not do anything with those parts, so  I'm taking it indicative of layout only..

With the switch closed (that is, conducting) it behaves as a classic [multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator)  switching between the two states rapidly. with the switch open it changes to an [eccles-jordan flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) preserving the last multivibrator state.

Choosing the correct resistors to get both behaviors could be tricky.

Comment: Nope, the transistors as shown don't give gain through the loop, won't oscillate.  Also D1 gives ~0.3V supply voltage, can't light LEDs or turn on transistors.  Perhaps it's a multivibrator circuit with multiple mistakes in the schematic.

Comment: the parts values (includibg supply voltage) are the defaults from the drawing package. I didn't take them as meaningful at all.

Comment: Also need to use NPNs, not PNPs wired for gain <1.

Comment: yes. I missed that.

Comment: Yeah i couldne be bothered to find the actual values for the resistors and capacitors :/. If you wanted to make this circuit work without the values do you just keep on guessing and adjust or is there an easy way to find the appropriate values?

Answer (score 1):

Does it actually work?

The diode drop of D1 should keep both transistors turned off permanently, as well as preventing LEDs from ever lighting up.

Hmmm, might this be a homework assignment where you're supposed to debug it, remove all the flaws and make it work?

The classic "decision maker" is an astable flip-flop which blinks back and forth at a few KHz, where opening the switch freezes the state, leaving one LED lit.  It's like flipping a coin, giving "random" heads/tails when you stop the spinning.  But as drawn, the above circuit won't do this.  Supply voltage is wrong, transistor hookup is wrong.  (Resistor values don't look quite right but may be OK depending on supply voltage used.)